# Uber webhook not triggering for driver_canceled, completed

Tags: uber-api

I am currently using sandbox-api to test my webhooks

If I send `{"status": "accepted"}` or `{"status": "arriving"}` webhooks are being invoked as expected

If I send `{"status": "driver_canceled"}` after `{"status": "accepted"}` `requests.receipt_ready` is invoked, but `requests.status_changed` is not

If I send `{"status": "completed"}` after `{"status": "accepted"}`, nothing is invoked.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: We resolved this issue and you should now be received the webhooks as expected.